# Solving the Schrödinger equation as a service?

Tags: density-functional-theory, ab-initio-calculations, one-topic-per-answer, high-performance-computing, from-chem-se

Does anyone know of a company with a cloud-based service which takes some representation of a molecule as an input, and then somehow solves the Schrödinger equation to some level of accuracy and reasonable time frame, then spits out the energy levels of orbitals as outputs?

My guess is that no company does this today, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for moving this here. Did you remove it from the other site? (the moderators can get grumpy if there is duplicate postings).

Comment: I'll do it for you!

Comment: If you have money to spend, ok. But, why not look for a scientific collaboration?

Comment: Is this a shopping question?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149573/7772)

Comment: @Mast while other sites on the network have rules about "shopping questions", the community consensus on Matter Modeling so far has been to allow questions seeking recommendations on a software or service.

Comment: As Cody and Mast mention, it is discouraged to post the same question on multiple sites on the network. It makes it tougher for future readers to find where an answer is and can lead to repeated effort when similar answers are given on each site. You should either remove the question on Chem (it seems to fit better here) or include a link to the Chem question in this post (and vice versa).

Comment: Are you looking specifically for the scientific expertise, or do you just need time on a big computer?  Would something like AWS or other cloud compute providers be an option (ie: do you already know how to calculate this stuff and just need a big cluster to run it on?)

Comment: If your answer to @J...'s question is that you're looking for cloud servers, please see: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4635/5 and this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1515/5 and this https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1613/5

Comment: Thanks for the various responses.  I have deleted the original question on the chemistry stack exchange, but thanks anyway to Nike Dattani for the offer to remove it.  This is not a "shopping question" - I am not looking to purchase anything.  Nor am I looking for something like AWS or another cloud compute provider.  It is very interesting to see all the speculation as to the motivation behind my question!  Without revealing everything, the motivation has more to do with investigation of the state of the art in industry.  If you wish to know more, contact me directly.

Comment: Note that the appropriate theory to use will, of course, depend massively on the size of the molecule, the number of electrons and the atomic numbers of the atoms that make up the molecule. The level of theory that can be applied to H2O, an individual water moelcule, is, of course, very different to what could be applied to a large protein, for example......

Comment: The point I want to make here is that generally people specialise in codes appropriate for different types of molecules or sizes of molecules and so the service that you describe in your question to be able to take any molecule will need either to

(1) have lots of different theoretical approaches available to do a good job on all molecules

or

(2) have a restricted number of theoretical approaches available (maybe one or two) so that it works well for some types of molecules, but is not optimised for other types of molecules.

Comment: is it just me or are all the services listed below basically just tutorial level stuff? I see no hardcore thermodynamic/transport/kinetics going on

Comment: Why tutorial level? It looks like state-of-the-art quantum chemistry. But they most likely don't solve a complex research question, just perform an individual computational step unless you arrange a stronger collaboration.

Answer (score 16):

## SciCalQ

The company does more than solving the Schroedinger equation. From its [site](https://www.scicalq.com/computational-chemistry-service/):

> SciCalQ’s solid background in computational chemistry and quantum physics own extensive experiences in solving practical and academic problems with scientific computing.

They do:

#### Density Functional Theory (DFT) Computation

- Geometric Configuration: Bond length, bond angle, lattice parameters, stable configuration, surface reconstruction, defects, vacancies, active sites, etc.
- Electronic Properties: HOMO/LUMO , energy band structure, conduction band, valence band position, DOS, electron cloud density, carrier mobility, Fermi level, etc.

#### Molecular dynamics (MD)

- Force Field for MD: Force field describes the interactions in/between moleculars in molecular dynamics simulations. We can obtain accurate force field for users.
- Binding Free Energy: Predicting the binding free energy of ligands to macromolecules can have great practical values in drugs discovery. We rovide one-stop service to finish this prediction.
- Bio-related Simulation: Polysaccharide molecular docking, molecular surface calculation, biological enzyme catalysis calculation, protein interaction analysis, transmembrane transport mechanism calculation, etc.

For ordering, you need to fill a web form where you:

- Discuss one by one according to the system and properties you need to calculate.
- Describe the system and intermediate process you need to calculate in detail (may be conjecture), and provide relevant literature.

Comment: I reached out to SciCalQ.  They never responded to my inquiry.

Answer (score 13):

## Protheragen

Protheragen offers a [Quantum Chemistry Service](https://aimed.protheragen.com/quantum-chemistry-service.html) which includes:

- ECD calculation service (absolute configuration determination)
- Quantitative calculations (quantum chemical calculations)
- QM, QM/MM, QM/MD
- Catalytic reaction mechanism calculation
- Transition state search and energy calculation
- Chemical reaction pathway and potential energy surface calculation
- Spectrum calculation, resonance frequency calculation
- Calculation of thermodynamic properties
- Enzyme catalytic mechanism simulation

The price is not made readily available, but they have a contact form on the website that I linked at the beginning of this answer, where you can discuss your project and pricing with them.

Comment: I reached out to Protheragen.  After an initial response, the salesperson never got back to me.

Comment: If you are seriously looking into having some simulations done for you, email me at nike@hpqc.org or email our reception at info@hpqc.org and we'll do it for you faster, more accurately, and for cheaper than whatever other services you find. I simply didn't want to "advertise" HPQC Labs in an answer because it would be considered "spam" to advertise my own Lab.

Comment: Thank you, Nike.  I will contact you directly.

Answer (score 8):

**QSimulate**

They advertise their ability to perform high throughput quantum mechanical simulations as well as large scale simulations on their web page. An e-mail address is provided for collaboration inquiries and other questions.

https://qsimulate.com/technology.html

An exemplary application is reported here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08725

Answer (score 3):

**Good Chemistry**

A new company called [Good Chemistry](https://goodchemistry.com/), a spinoff company of [1QBit](https://1qbit.com/), has released a beta-version of their [QEMIST Cloud](https://goodchemistry.com/qemist-cloud/) service which purports to do exactly what you're asking about. From their website:

> QEMIST Cloud is an engine that enables faster, more accurate, and scalable ways to perform computational chemistry simulations. Our new platform leverages easily and readily accessible computers on the cloud to perform chemistry simulations that were previously intractable even on expensive, high-performance computing environments.